# Why does it not pick up the jquery function?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have found a jquery function where the default value "$" will be replaced with for example "default value". But I don't know why it isn't picking up this function.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.Label("Product price")
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x =>  x.P_price, null, new { @class = "form-control" , 
     @Value = "$", @id = "txtTitle" })
     <p style="color:red;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.P_price)</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            if ($("#txtTitle").val() == "$") {
                $("#txtTitle").val("Default Value");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<form>` element

Try the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form>
     @Html.Label("Product price")
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x =>  x.P_price, null, new { @class = "form-control" , 
     @Value = "$", @id = "txtTitle" })
    <p style="color:red;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.P_price)</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and tested it on my side and it worked. What kind of error do you get?